# How to include regular JavaScript scripts/libraries for server-side calculation with Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I need to calculate the distance between two users, captured via Geolocation API. I have found the script, written in vanilla JS, that takes the Lat/Long pairs of both users and returns the distance between them:

```
var distance = distVincenty(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
```

Please scroll to the bottom of the page for the script source: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html

I have tried using `require('./lib/vincenty');`, however each time I call `distVincenty()` it returns `distVincenty is not defined`.

So how do I include/require `vincenty.js` into Express bunch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a read of ["understanding Node.js' require"](http://jherdman.github.com/2010-04-05/understanding-nodejs-require.html).

What's happening is that just because you've required the file it doesn't mean that you get all of the functions in it. What you get is the functions the file adds to the special `exports` object on the return value of the require call.